# Do sleep and usleep behave differently internally, in PHP?

Tags: php, cpu, sleep, usleep

I have a socket server listening to a connection for incoming data and writing outgoing data during pauses in input.  Since this is in a loop I am making a `sleep` call in order to allow other processes to have some CPU time while my process is not expecting input right away.

I know `sleep` does this, but does `usleep` also return execution to the OS?  I am suspicious because I know that, traditionally, the `sleep` syscall only accepts seconds, and a VERY old book I have read about C programming ten years ago said that to "sleep" for shorter intervals involves hacks like making an infinite loop to essentially simulate the `sleep` call but not cede CPU time to other processes.  (This book may have been wrong, or may no longer be accurate, I'm just telling you what it said.)

I am using Linux, PHP versions 5.6 and 7.1

thank you

Comment: I suspect it's OS level. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html

Comment: You can test it. Use `usleep(10000)` and watch your CPU load.

Comment: You could use `select` or `poll` to wait for input to arrive. Your program will respond faster and use less cpu.

Answer (score 0):

It is platform-dependent, but on Linux you can use this simple script to test:

```
$start = microtime(true);

while(true){
        while(microtime(true) - $start < .9){}
}

//while(true){
//      usleep(900000);
//}
```

Run it with `php test.php & top -d 0.1` the first time to observe what a false `sleep` looks like, kill the spawned php process after done inspecting `top`, comment out the first `while` loop and uncomment the second one, re-run the script and note the CPU usage.

Thanks to Halcyon for giving me the idea to test it myself.